# python defaultdict how to use it instead of function

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the meaning of

```
def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

t = tree()
```

How can I do it without function?

```
t = defaultdict()
```

It's not the same.

Comment: Yes, it's not the same. What do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: `tree` is a function which, when called, returns a defaultdict which calls `tree` for non-existent values, i.e. creates a defaultdict which uses `tree` for each non-existent value. Since this definition is recursive, it's not really possible to make it a one-liner.

Comment: the same behavior @mkrieger1